# REGEX - regex starts with space or ends with space or starts with > and ends with < and has a text 'ghghfg'

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace a XML file with few strings. My text can be in the following formats.

```
>myText<
>This is myText<
>This is myText and I need it changed<
```

I am trying to build a regex to catch the phrase only in the text of the XML tags so the text should be between  > and < tags.

Comment: XML is not a regular language. Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job. [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4642212)

Comment: Can you share a larger portion of the XML file? In general you should use a parser and XPath but if regex is really the only available tool then sharing more of the file would help.

Comment: @user4642212 Albeit comical, that linked answer is utterly useless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for the word `myText` within tags and wish to capture the entire string inside the tag then try this:

```
(?<=>)[^<]*myText[^<]*
```

- `(?<=>)` - look for a `>`
- `[^<]*` - capture everything which is not `<`
- `myText` - make sure `myText` exists
- `[^<]*` - capture everything which is not `<`

You did not specify a programming language but if you're using Notepad++ then this should be compatible.

https://regex101.com/r/MPnh8J/1

Comment: I am using JavaScript and my main aim is to just find the string and replace it with another one.

Comment: This one helps, how can I just select only the string ?. I am getting the entire statement inside > < currently.